# MongoDB/ElasticSearch Queries based on a list of combinated values

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a mongoDB database with a collection of songs. Each document contains a title, an artist name and some other info.

My app allows users to load their own playlist. Basically I end up with a list of titles/artists and want to match it with those in my database. If the song isn't in my database I save it, otherwise I add it to the user's account.

What is the most efficient way to search all these songs, based on the title and artist value? Right now I'm looping on each song from the list and search it in the database but it's very time consuming. (There can be thousands of songs).

I know mongoDB has a `$in` operator but I don't think it's enough for my problem.
I'm also using ElasticSearch, maybe there is a better way to do what I want with it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ElasticSearch you can easily do this.

Put your songs to Elasticsearch like this:

`POST songscollection\data
{
  "artist": "Artist3",
  "title": "Song1"
}`

Then create one query to Elasicsearch with all songs from playlist

```
POST songscollection\data\_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
     "should" : [
            {
              "bool": { 
                "must": [
                  { "match" : { "artist" : "Artist1" } },
                  { "match" : { "title" : "Song1" } }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  { "match" : { "artist" : "Artist3" } },
                  { "match" : { "title" : "Song1" } }
                ]
              }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

You will get all songs which exists in DB and easily map with user playlist in code.